# How to leave images in bin folder untouched while compiling

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an invisible image in an android app. It's used for an image map.

The problem is, that the image is compressed while compiling, so that the image in the bin folder or in the apk is not the same than the image in the res folder. Now when you click on the image the function that detects the color of the pixel returns the wrong color.
If I copy the original image into the bin folder by hand erverything works fine.

Is there a trick to get Eclipse not to compress images while compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your bitmap in the res/raw folder.
From the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables-from-images):

> Note: Image resources placed in res/drawable/ may be automatically
>   optimized with lossless image compression by the aapt tool during the
>   build process. For example, a true-color PNG that does not require
>   more than 256 colors may be converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color
>   palette. This will result in an image of equal quality but which
>   requires less memory. So be aware that the image binaries placed in
>   this directory can change during the build. If you plan on reading an
>   image as a bit stream in order to convert it to a bitmap, put your
>   images in the res/raw/ folder instead, where they will not be
>   optimized.

You can also apparently [rename your image *.jet](http://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/wiki/TalkTranscript) to prevent compression.

Comment: Putting the image into the raw folder has no effect. But renaming the image from .png to .jet works fine. Thanks.